# Creating SEO Friendly URLs with .htaccess and php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to generate SEO friendly URLs using PHP by using a rewrite in our .htaccess file, but I can't get it to work (I've researched many of the related topics on StackExhange and elsewhere, but to no avail).

I'm attempting to make the content of this URL: http://199.119.123.135/surety-bonds/city.php?state=california&city=sacramento

...also display on the cleaner URL version here: http://199.119.123.135/surety-bonds/california/sacramento/

I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^surety-bonds/([a-zA-Z]+)$ city.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L,NC]
```

Any idea why the cleaner URL displays a 404 error?

Thanks!

Comment: Your pattern is looking for a state but no city. Hint $1 refers to the first pair of brackets in the pattern, what does $2 refer to?

Comment: plus `surety-bonds/` is missing in front of `city.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+surety-bonds/city\.php\?state=([^&]+)&city=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /surety-bonds/%1/%2/? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^^surety-bonds/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /surety-bonds/city.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: That worked! I'm trying to do a very similar URL rewrite but am running into an error. I created a separate thread here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676599/get-page-id-value-and-display-in-url-via-htaccess), but so far have not fixed the issue. Could you take a look since you seem familiar with what I'm trying to do?