# Get page id value and display in URL via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to display SEO friendly URLs by using a rewrite in our .htaccess file, but I can't get it to work (I've researched many of the related topics on StackExhange and elsewhere, but to no avail). I'd like to get the value of the id on this page...

http://199.119.123.135/info/tool_surety_company.php?id=1

...and display the id value in the URL instead of the ugly "tool_surety_company.php?id=1".

I'm going for a result like this: http://199.119.123.135/info/travelers-group

I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+info/tool_surety_company\.php\?id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /info/%1/? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^^info/([^/]+)/?$ /info/tool_surety_company.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

But I'm receiving a 404 error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: travelers-group < how is that saved on the database? does the database have url slugs?

far as i can see you can achieve

http://199.119.123.135/info/1/travelers-group something like that

Comment: remove double ^ from last rewrite rule, just leave one

Comment: also add L flag to the last rule

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion, but still returns the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: I'd guess you're getting a 404 because the server has no idea what to load for the new url you're directing the user to.

Comment: @Sergio there is no need to add the L flag if thats already the last RewriteRule

Comment: add R flag to last rule and look what result are you getting

Comment: What url are you trying?

Comment: I've tried all of your suggestions above, but none worked. @Justin Levi Winter I responded to your question below regarding the id and our database. This is the URL I'm testing on [link](http://199.119.123.135/info/tool_surety_company.php?id=1)

Answer (score 0):

There might be something I'm misunderstanding here but I believe there would need to be a mechanism on the server side code to load the correct content for the new "seo-friendly url". In other words, sure, you can redirect the user to show a different url but how is the server going to know what content to load for that new url?

Here's a good resource for putting together a simple example. 
https://moz.com/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls

Update:

From here - https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

> TROUBLESHOOTING
>
> 404 Not Found
>
> Examine the new URL in your browser closely. Does it match a file that
>   exists on the server in the new location specified by the rewrite
>   rule? You may have to make your rewrite rule more broad (you may be
>   able to remove the $1 from the second string). This will direct
>   rewrites to the main index page given in the second string. Or, you
>   may need to copy files from your old location to the new location.

In other words, the only reason you would be getting a 404 is because the server does not find the file that is requested as defined in the URL visible in your browser address bar.

> Htaccess Rewrites are enabled by using the Apache module mod_rewrite,
>   which is one of the most powerful Apache modules and features
>   availale. Htaccess Rewrites through mod_rewrite provide the special
>   ability to Rewrite requests internally as well as Redirect request
>   externally.
>
> When the url in your browser's location bar stays the same for a
>   request it is an internal rewrite, when the url changes an external
>   redirection is taking place. This is one of the first, and one of the
>   biggest mental-blocks people have when learning about mod_rewrite.

More info from here: 
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Hey Justin. The id value is pulled from our database, and is already dynamically displaying for the page title and headers. The id value for this page [link](http://199.119.123.135/info/tool_surety_company.php?id=1) is "Travelers Group". Am I making sense?

Comment: I also tried example one in the link you provided, but it didn't work :(

Comment: right, but how does your website know what to load for "/info/travelers-group"? There is no built in mechanism to reverse the newly created and requested url to the ID value of the original url. 

There would need to be some PHP script to parse the new URL parameters and load the new content for the new url

Comment: As I understand it, The htaccess file is hit prior to the php page so the redirect would happen before the php content is actually rendered

Comment: I got a very similar rewrite working here [link](http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/surety-bonds/pennsylvania/harrisburg/). Both "pennsylvania" and "harrisburg" are rewritten by pulling the "state" and "city" values. The actual URL for the page above is http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/surety-bonds/city.php?state=37&city=13. Shouldn't I be able to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Not with an htaccess rewrite rule alone. That example must also include some additional server-side code to parse the url and pass those variables to the php page

Comment: you're not just rewriting the url, you're redirecting the request

Comment: Isn't that what's happening with the title and headers on this page? 199.119.123.135/info/tool_surety_company.php?id=1. Those are being dynamically displayed using the id. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think the fact that the titles and header are displaying on that url are not directly applicable in what you're trying to do here. Yes, the title and header is displayed dynamically based on the id value for that url. 

If you redirect the user to a new URL - What PHP script do you have at that new url to dynamically parse the new url to load the content? You would need to have a php file at the destination you're trying to direct the user to.

Comment: @user2366546 if you use the rules you're trying to use then a URL like this `http://example.com/info/travelers-group` is going to send this to your PHP `/info/tool_surety_company.php?id=travelers-group` That's why you get a 404 because id is not a number anymore. You'd have to look it up by the name in the DB.

Comment: So from what I understand, I'd have to change the logic in the tool_surety_company.php file. The current logic is `$suretyID = $_GET['id'];`. Would this logic have to be reversed in order for the rewrite to work?

Comment: Yeah, as @PanamaJack said, in the php file located in `/info/travelers-group`, you'd need to use that url to return the correct data

Comment: @user2366546 yes the logic would change. maybe change the id to name and do `$suretyname = $_GET['name']` and search by name in the DB. Caveat would be duplicate names so make sure your names are unique

Comment: Alright, so I changed the logic and it working now. However, my rewrite in the .htaccess file is causing an error. See here: http://199.119.123.135/info/tool_surety_company.php?name=old-republic-group. Any ideas?